# Imported excel null date inputted as 1970-01-01

Tags: php, laravel, date, phpspreadsheet, phpoffice

I'm using phpoffice/phpspreadsheet as the packages. When im testing the function of importing excel into database. I noticed all the null dates are now 1970-01-01. How do I fix it?
Following is the sample code.

```
'Registrant_date'=>\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\Date::excelToDateTimeObject($row['Registrant_date'])->format('Y-m-d'),
```

Comment: What do you want as *null dates*? 1970-0101 is start of epoch in Unix (and so in many system which derived from it), so 0 is that date.  Just filter out the dates with 0, and put what you want, and format only dates with a positive number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in comments, compare date to zero.

```php
$reg_date = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\Date::excelToDateTimeObject($row['Registrant_date']);

'Registrant_date'=> date_timestamp_get($reg_date) ? $reg_date->format('Y-m-d') : null,
```